# How to replace missing value by the mean of the rows

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

So I have rows and I want to replace the `nan` values with mean of each row.

For example:

```
x = [[2,4,nan,5,3],[2,3,5,nan],...]
```

I know that we could use the `Imputer` (axis=1) but with `simpleImputer` we don't have this option anymore.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use raw numpy:

```
x = np.where(
    np.isnan(x),
    np.nanmean(x, axis=1, keepdims=True),
    x
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With combination of [`np.nanmean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) + [`np.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html#numpy.isnan) functions:

Sample array:

```
x = np.array([[2, 4, np.nan, 5, 3], [2, 3, 5, np.nan, 8]])
```

---

```
x[np.where(np.isnan(x))] = np.nanmean(x, axis=1)
```

---

```
array([[2. , 4. , 3.5, 5. , 3. ],
       [2. , 3. , 5. , 4.5, 8. ]])
```